# Webpack 5 does not support polyfills for Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, polyfills

I have an npm package that works on Angular as well as on Node.js.
Lately, I have started to use my package with Angular v12 projects.
I am getting errors like:

> BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js
> core modules by default. This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

I need those packages (e.g. 'path'), and I cannot switch to the Webpack alternative (e.g. 'path-browserify') since I need this to work on nodejs.

The error says:

> If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
> - install 'path-browserify'

Installing 'path-browserify' is easy. However, the error does not state where to add the fallback. I found in some posts that suggest I need to add it to Webpack.config.js. But in the Angular project, there is no such file; adding it did not have any effect. And even if there were such a file, it would not help me because I am an npm package, and I cannot change files in the application that uses me.

I can write a workaround for the 'path' package. However, other packages raised that error. Some of the packages (e.g., suppertest) are not meant to work from webpack, and I am not using them when running on angular, but since they are in my code, the webpack still raises this error. I am also using other packages that use themselves problematic packages like 'path' or 'stream,' and I cannot change them. How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Have you try to use Babel 

Answer (score -1):

As the error states, you should add `resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }` in your webpack config file.

```js
// webpack.config.js

module.export = {
  ...
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      path: require.resolve("path-browserify")
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Like the OP, I am using Angular. The problem is `webpack.config.js` is located under /node-modules/ and should not be modified (e.g. changes will be erased next time `webpack` is updated). I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: You can use patch-package, it applies a patch on lib inside node_modules. Check it out https://github.com/ds300/patch-package