# Is there an alternative to next/Image and next/Link anywhere that I could use in React JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to get some code that I did not write working for Monday.  The code makes heavy use of `next/Image` and `next/Link` but I am encountering [very confusing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76741328/5869304) every single time I try to include the `next` package in even the simplest wizard-generated, boiler-plate react application.

It is likely I'm just too inexperienced in react and node and javascript in general to solve this configuration issue in just 2 days.  I'll keep trying but I am not optimistic.

But is there some sort of alternative to `next/Image` and `next/Link` somewhere in react or something that I could use?

Comment: Of course, ```next/Image``` is a high level abstraction of ```<img .../>``` tag, and with ```<a>``` tag for ```next/Link```. So to answer your question, yes there is some sort of alternative to next/Image and next/Link that you could use

Comment: Apologies, I realize it's a bit of a dumb question but what then does next/Image and Link give me that I would not get with those things?

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter.  I don't need to make this work pretty.  I just need to make it work to demonstrate a concept.  I didn't really understand that they were just simple wrappers for those HTML tags.  Replacing them as you suggested is at least allowing me to get by.  Thank you @JeanJacquesGourdin

Comment: [next/link](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link) and [next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images) are by no means just simple wrappers around `<img` and `<a`. They provide prefetching, client-side navigation, image optimization, and more. -- But if `<img` and `<a` are sufficient for your purpose, then you can use them.